# How to invert a damage formula?

Tags: mathematics, algorithm

I have created simple damage formula based on source percent, which return fixed percent of damage.

```
DAMAGE_PERCENT = Exp(Log(100) * (1 - (100 - SOURCE_PERCENT) / 150)
```

Here is the result:

```
percent[0]: 4.641589
percent[1]: 4.786301
percent[2]: 4.935525
....
percent[98]: 94.04449
percent[99]: 96.97654
percent[100]: 100
```

How can I make it return same results but with reversed SOURCE_PERCENT value?

So percent[0] should return 100 and percent[100] return 4.641589?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write a wrapper that takes your input and subtracts it from 100

```
float GetDamageInverse(int percent) {
    return GetDamage(100-percent);
}
```

Or you can change your equation to replace the `100 - SOURCE_PERCENT` with `SOURCE_PERCENT`.

Comment: I should add, I'm getting different results from your equation. You sure you entered your formula into your code correctly?

Comment: Oh God,     
I have made wrong question. LOL  
I don't know how, I'm feel so stupid...  
I am so sorry.

About my formula, yes, it was correctly. Here is a code:  
    return exp(log(100) * (1 - (100 - percent) / 150));

Comment: @NeverForget Please don't completely change the question after someone has answered. If you have a new question, ask that as a new question. I took time to answer your question here, changing it to an entirely new question invalidates any answers you received.